# Yugoslavia ISO country code clarification

Tags: internationalization

I see two ISO codes for Yugoslavia.

1. 891 - Yugoslavia and
2. 807 - Macedonia, the Former Yugoslav Republic Of

Can someone clarify which one to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yugoslavia no longer exists. The nation that was Yugoslavia has now been split into several smaller nations, one of which is Macedonia.

The 'Former Yugoslav Republic of' notation is only used for Macedonia (ie not by any of the other states that were previously part of Yugoslavia), and isn't generally used much anyway (I'm not even sure if it's still part of Macedonia's official name), but it may be useful to distinguish it from the Greek province of Macedonia, which is geographically very close to it.

There has been quite a lot of change in that region in recent years; make sure you have an up-to-date ISO codes list.

Comment: there is an argument between Greeks and Macedonians. Greeks refuse categorically that the name "Macedonia" denote anything other than a Greek region, hence the FYROM stuff.

Comment: @abatishchev Only Macedonia have notation 'Former Yugoslav Republic'. More info about these facts you can find here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breakup_of_Yugoslavia.

Answer (score 4):

Yugoslavia (Jugoslavija) doesn't exist any more. Macedonia is one of 6 former republic. Serbia and Montenegro disintegrated a few years ago. Now, all former republics are independent countries: Serbia, Croatia, Slovenia, Bosna and Hercegovina, Montenegro and Macedonia.

Answer (score 3):

- Yugoslavia
- YU, YUG, 891
- 1974–2003
- YUCS
- Name changed to Serbia and Montenegro (CS, SCG, 891)
- Alphabetic codes used for both SFR Yugoslavia  and FR Yugoslavia
- Numeric code changed from 890 (for SFR Yugoslavia) to 891 (for FR Yugoslavia) in 1993
- YU currently transitionally reserved
- .yu deleted
- ISO 3166-2:YU changed to ISO 3166-2:CS

[en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-3#Current_codes)

P.S. As far as Yugoslavia doesn't exist any more, what for do you need its code?

Comment: You need to maintain such codes for compatibility reasons (some old apps may use them).

Answer (score 3):

FR Yugoslavia doesn't exist anymore. It is disintegrated in Yugoslav wars. From the former Yugoslavia, currently, there are established six independent countries from 6 former Yugoslav republics. More about Yugoslavia you can read [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yugoslavia). About disintegration of Yugoslavia you can read [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breakup_of_Yugoslavia).

These countries are (name, local name and country code):

- Serbia (Srbija) - 688
- Croatia (Hrvatska) - 191
- Bosnia and Herzegovina (Bosna i Hercegovina) - 070
- Slovenia (Slovenija) - 705
- FYR Macedonia (Makedonija) - 807
- Montengro (Crna Gora) - 499

Please, note the three crucial facts:

- All of these countries are independent (and have their own country
  code);
- Legal successor is Serbia as a legal successor of Serbia and
  Montenegro, which is legal successor of FR Yugoslavia;
- FYR Macedonia has that name only because Greece does not allow
  Macedonia country name for independent country (due to possible geo-political and historical misunderstandings related to Greece area - Macedonia).

Answer (score 2):

Neither.

Wikipedia has a [list of currently-assigned ISO-3166 country codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_numeric), and also links to the source UN documents.

Answer (score 0):

891 is now Serbia & Montenegro. Yugoslavia as a country no longer exists.

Comment: Serbia and Montenegro are two countries now.

Comment: 807 - Macedonia, the Former Yugoslav Republic Of can I show that in my dropdown list then?

Comment: 891 is onsolete. It's been replaced by 499 (Montenegro) and 688 (Serbia)

Comment: @Pangea yes you can show that code, we have 2 mil. population, maybe someone will use your app :) :)